# git merge: conflicts in files that haven't been touched

Tags: git, linux-kernel

I'll try to illustrate my problem by the following example:

I have linux kernel git repository containing 2.6.31-6 version with some modifications. I'd like to merge it with, say, 2.6.32. But during git pull <2.6.32 repository path> I see a lot of conflicts that have to be resolved manually in files I haven't ever touched.

What's wrong with that? I mean, git has full history of commits and it has an information about files that were modified after "parent commit" and files that were not. Why can't it apply the very last modifications on the files that were not touched?

**UPDATE1:** @DanAloni and @KevinBallard have explained why there appear conflicts while merging -rc with newer stable release.

But is there a way to reduce number of manual conflicts particularly in situation when -rc is merged with release?

**UPDATE2:** Thanks to @DanAloni for explanation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure that the version you are describing as `2.6.31-6` is in the history of `2.6.32`? As far as I know about Linux kernel versioning, `2.6.31-6` sounds to me like `2.6.31` plus 'stable branch patches'. This can surely conflict with history that branched from `2.6.31` release onward to the `2.6.32` stable tree. So, I think you are trying to merge a stable or patched **fork** of `2.6.31` with the stable tree of `2.6.32`. It surely not what git describes as 'fast-forward', and I certainly expect conflicts there.

Comment: Yes, it should be in history just because there's a tag corresponding to 2.6.31-rc6: git tag -l | grep 2.6.31-rc6

Comment: @DanKruchinin: That doesn't mean it's in the history of 2.6.32. If you say `git log 2.6.32..2.6.31-rc6` (assuming `2.6.32` and `2.6.31-rc6` are the names of the tags) does that print anything? If it does, it means 2.6.31-6 is *not* an ancestor of 2.6.32 and that Dan Aloni is likely correct.

Comment: @KevinBallard Thanks, that makes sense. Is there any cheap way to merge -rcN with higher stable release?

Comment: Just the existence of the tag says nothing about the history of the branch you are merging to. `git tag -l` just prints all the tags in the database regardless of the history of any branch. There's a git command that tells what tags are **contained** in the history of the current branch - can't recall it of the top of my head, though.

Comment: The 'cheap way' to do so would be to apply a patch that reverts all changes between 2.6.31 and 2.6.31-6, and then try to merge 2.6.32. Note that you might get conflicts on that revert. Generating the diff for that revert is something in the lines of `git diff HEAD..v2.6.31`, assuming that the current branch represents 2.6.31-6. You can take the diff and try to apply it as a commit with with another git command `git apply`.

Comment: Also, I forgot to mention, as far as I know from Linux kernel development perspective, the kernel hackers are doing their best to take all patches of the forked stable trees and apply them into the ongoing kernel development effort. This means that 2.6.32-rc should already include **some** of the work done to make 2.6.31 more stable. BTW, there's a 2.6.32 stable tree that was forked after 2.6.32 was released. Wouldn't it be easier to take your work (which I hope is not a huge amount of changes) and try to rebase it on top of 2.6.32?